# Implementing C library function in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

What are the disadvantages of implementing C library in C++? The library is going to be used to build Windows application for regular PC using Visual Studio 2008 or newer. It is not clear why the specs state that it should be C library. I am guessing that what they want is plain C-API, not pure C lib. But my boss disagrees.

Anyway, what I want to do is to `extern "C"` all function declarations and use C++ in implementation files. I did some testing and everything worked just fine even when the application was compiled as C (by changing project option in Visual Studio).

Comment: I think you need to ask your customer what they mean by that. If they are going to use this library on embedded device without libsdtc++, you're screwed.

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio specifically, but in general if a library is to be linked into a C program, creating it in C++ (with extern "c" declarations) could cause problems unless the linker knows to perform a C++ startup. If you might ever need to port this as a C-friendly library to another compiler, implementing in pure C is probably a safer decision.

Comment: BTW, I'd agree with you. That your boss thinks a client would care about the source language of compiled code rather than the API into said code, makes me wonder how he's the boss of _anyone_.

Comment: @Tomalak:  C++ libraries are likely to require C++ runtimes and perhaps C++ initialization, making them unwelcome in C programs.  If I asked for a C library and got a C++ library with a wrapper, I'd be upset.

Comment: Another example: if the customer is going to be receiving the source code, they may want it in C so that they can understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen people do that for, say, exposing STL collections to C programs.  If you are sure that the library will only be used in environments with sane C/C++ compilers (say, VS and gcc only) I think this is a pretty safe thing to do from the technical perspective.  N
ow, it sounds like you have some sort of outside requirement at play here, but obviously we can't comment on that.  Might be worse double checking with the requirements source?

UPDATE: oh, I should mention that it will affect the DLLs that your library will require.  Like the C++ runtime DLL will need to be loaded in addition to CRT.

Answer (score 0):

The extern c is used like all the time to port some functionality from c to c++. For instance the new operator inturn calls the malloc() from std c. This is one good example of c library being given a c++ look. new operator makes it much more easy to allocate memory and in addition to that it also allows a lot of functionality like operator overloading which is not available in c. My guess would be to add more functionality to and to make neat interfaces.

If you are considering about disadvatanges then it might be related compiler specific problems where the ABL generated for a c++ program differs from that of the C and if the compiler is not able to differentiate between the two then you struck with it.

I am not sure if this is what you are seeking for, if not try this link it might be of some assistance.

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=180

Answer (score 0):

If they are going to use it for a C programm, i.e. the `main()` function is compiled by a C compiler, then you have to be very carefully with your C++ library. The problem is that the c programm will not execute any constructor for static variables. So you have to omit  the usage of any static variables with constructor. This is easy for your library itself, but you have to check every call to a library C++ function if it relies on the existance of a static initialized variable (e.g. `std::cout`, `std::cin` etc.).